# Pointer to pointer in struct

Tags: c, pointers, struct

Could someone help explaining why this part of my code isn't working?

```
typedef struct {
    char *something;
} random;

random *rd;
rd->something = calloc(40, sizeof(char)); // This is the line which crashes
strncpy(rd->something, aChar, 40);
```

The program works if I write it as such:

```
random rd;
rd.something = calloc(40, sizeof(char));
strncpy(rd.something, aChar, 40);
```

But I think this is wrong when handling memory, that's why I want help with the first scenario.

Comment: the second approach is the correct one. you can fix the first too, but you probably don't need it.

Comment: `random *rd;` , `rd` is uninitialize. needs `rd = malloc(sizeof(random));` or `rd = &random_obj;`

Comment: in first approach first you need to allocate memory for rd and then allocate memory for something. Then it'' work fine.
In second case you are allocating memory to rd on stack so no need to allocate memory for structure and one allocation for something will be required which you are doing, hence it's working. Hope this answers your question.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the second one (it's better than the first) as long as you don't need the object to persist beyond its scope. By the way, `sizeof(char)` is 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no memory allocated to the struct pointed by rd.

Try:

```
typedef struct {
    char *something;
} random;

random *rd = malloc (sizeof(random));
rd->something = calloc(40, sizeof(char)); // This is the line which crashes
strncpy(rd->something, aChar, 40);
```

Comment: It's better not add the cast to the malloc function

Comment: [Don't cast the result of `malloc()`.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/3233393)

Answer (score 0):

It is because your defined pointer

```
random *rd;
```

is not properly initialized and therefore you get a segmentation fault. The second version works, because you actually allocate `rd`. To make the first version work as well, allocate memory for `*rd` with

```
random *rd = (random*)malloc(sizeof(random));
```

Comment: it's not initalized as `NULL` - unless it's a global var.

Comment: You sure about that? I would think `random *rd` initializes to some garbage value.

Answer (score 0):

Case 1:

```
random *rd;

// Create *pointer* to struct of type random . Doesn't point to anything.

rd->something = calloc(40, sizeof(char)); 

// Use it by trying to acquire something which doesnt exist and it crashes
```

Case 2:

```
random rd;

// Create a random struct

rd.something = calloc(40, sizeof(char));

// Use it . Works good
```

===========================

For Case 1, you need to allocate a struct first , make the pointer point to it and then use the `->` operator to modify the values

Comment: in first case, it'll work if you allocate heap memory for rd first.

Answer (score 0):

It will work, but first allocate memory to rd.
rd = (random *) calloc(1,sizeof(random));